# How to get latlng value of a city using geocoder in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to get a latlng value of a city using the following code ... but i get result as "latlng value is undefined " my code is

```
geocoder.geocode( {'address': acity}, function(results, status) {
             if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                 latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
              }
        });
```

Update : If i display lat and lng values separately its been displayed , If made them assigned to latlng1 "latlng1 is undefined" its showing

Comment: What does `results[0].geometry.location.lat()` contain?

Comment: i hope it will contain latitude of the acity parameter i sent ...

Comment: Right, but can you check what it actually contains?  Whether or not it (and the corresponding lng()) contains a valid value will help you find the problem.

Comment: `var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(.....`

Comment: @ASGM i checked ...lat and lng values consists of latitude n longitude respectively ... its also getting assigned to latlng1 ... but its taking sometime ... am using that latlng1 value outside also ... the outside altlng1 is called 1st and its displaying undefined values .... later that only geocoder codings are executed

Comment: Then declare `var latlng1` GLOBAL

Comment: did that too ...but not working

Comment: You will need to add more code to question

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, the location is returned as a LatLng object. You don't need make a new LatLng object.

> geometry contains the following information:
>
> location contains the geocoded latitude,longitude value. Note that we
>   return this location as a LatLng object, not as a formatted string.

Example:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        window.test = results[0].geometry.location
         setTimeout(function() {
             console.log(window.test.lat());
             console.log(window.test.lng());
         }, 5000)
      } 
    });
```

Edit: I think I misunderstood, I think you're just wanting the latLng object in the global scope. I've edited the example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you're trying to do something like this:

```
var latlng1;

geocoder.geocode({
    'address': acity
}, function( results, status ) {
    if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(
            results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
            results[0].geometry.location.lng()
        );
    }
});

// Now do stuff with latlng1 here
```

That will never work, and there's no way you can make it work. As you discovered, the "now do stuff with latlng1" code runs *before* the results are received.

The geocoder API, like any JavaScript API that hits a server for data, is asynchronous. The API call returns immediately, and the callback function is called when the data is ready.

So what you need to do is *call* a function of your own when the data is ready, like this (also simplified to remove the redundant `LatLng` constructor call):

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': acity
}, function( results, status ) {
    if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        doStuffWithLatLng( results[0].geometry.location );
    }
});

function doStuffWithLatLng( latlng ) {
    // Now do stuff with latlng1 here
}
```

Or of course you could put the "do stuff" code right inside the geocoder callback:

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': acity
}, function( results, status ) {
    if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
        var latlng1 = results[0].geometry.location;
        // Now do stuff with latlng1 here
    }
});
```

Comment: i need to access latlng1 throughout the function ... i tried ur 1st example of passing it to a separate function ... but it didnt works ... still showing undefined value only for latlng1 .... its not possible for me to use 2nd example like within that IF statement as i need to access latlng1 value throughout the function

Comment: The thing is, you have to worry about *when* your `latlng1` data is available, not just *where* in your code it is available. You can certainly store the value in a global variable or such, but that doesn't help you with knowing *when* that variable is ready to use. The `geocoder.geocode()` function returns immediately, before the data is ready. The data isn't ready until your callback function gets called. Any code that uses this data should be in a function that you can call at that time, otherwise the data won't be ready.